# SUM() immutable transactions is that cachable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Environment:**

I have a `User`-model and every user `has_many :points_transactions`. A `PointsTransaction` has a field with `:amount`. If I want to know the (points) balance of a user, I'd have to `SUM("points_transactions"."amount")`. While over time the amount of transactions starts to grow (the are added every minute), the `SUM` will take more and more time *(see the simplified model code below)*.

**Question:**

What I was wondering is, since the transactions are more like a history of what happend and the past will never change, is it possible to `SUM()` the transactions, cache it in some way so that when a new transaction comes in, you can just use the cache + the new transaction amount.

**Clear example:**

User Bob (id: 1) has 5 points_transactions:

1. amount: +5
2. amount: +10
3. amount: -5
4. amount: +15
5. amount: -10

Bob wants to know his current balance so he uses `User.find(1).points_transactions.sum(:amount)`

Which returns: 15.

A new transaction comes in: +5. Since the `points_transactions` never change, is it not possible to just take the result of the previous `SUM()` and add +5 to it? Like:

15 (the previous SUM result) + 5 (new transaction) = 20

**Simplified model:**

```
# models/user.rb

# Table: users
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :points_transactions

  def points
    points_transactions.sum(:amount)
  end
end

# models/points_transaction.rb

# Table: points_transactions
# [Number] amount the points of the transaction (could be negative)
# [Int] user_id the user it is connected to
class PointsTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have heard it was possible on database level, but I could not find a way to actually do it. Would you guys solve this on database or on Rails level? Let me know!

Comment: Hey, But based on the model method when you call user.points, it will always sent you the sum. I am confusing about the same what are you asking for.

Comment: @Bharatsoni For now it does, until I find a better solution.